# Get all time slots (and exclude some) between two dates using moment.js (infinite loop issue ?)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, momentjs, infinite-loop

I'm a kind of newbie, and I'm trying (using `moment.js`) to get all timeslots between two dates excluding some. More precisely.

- I have a `start date` (say monday) and  `end date` (say wednesday)
- I want to get an `array` of all 30 minutes slots (monday 00:00, monday 00:30... tuesday 9:00, tuesday 09:30, tuesday 10:00...)
- **But** excluding - for example - slots before 9AM...

---

```
const dates = []

const now = moment(now).startOf('day').hour(9).minute(0).seconds(0)
const deadline = moment(end).hour(19).minute(0).seconds(0)    

while (now.diff(deadline) < 0) {
  if (now > now.hour(9)) {
    dates.push(now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
  }
  now.add(30, 'minutes')
}
```

Without `if` statement, things work (my array contains all days between my two dates). But with `if`, my browser **crashes** (infinite loop?).
But I do not know why... Any idea? I'd liked to learn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because moment object are mutable, so `now.hour(9)` (re)sets hour = 9 to `now` instance, so `now.diff(deadline) < 0` will be always true. See [Get + Set](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) setion of the docs:

> **Note:** All of these methods mutate the original moment when used as setters.

You can clone `now` (using [`clone()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) function or using `moment(now)`)  in your if condition.

Here a live sample:

```js
const dates = []

const now = moment().startOf('day').hour(9).minute(0).seconds(0)
const deadline = moment().hour(19).minute(0).seconds(0) 

while (now.diff(deadline) < 0) {
  if (now > moment(now).hour(9)) {
    dates.push(now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
  }
  now.add(30, 'minutes');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

As a general rule, do not compare moment object using `>` and `<`, use query methods like [`isAfter`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/), [`isBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) etc

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks
Using date-fns (lighter library): 

`while (isBefore(now, deadline)) {
      dates.push(now)
      now = addMinutes(now, 30)
    }`